# iPhone - accessing unknown getter method in a class

Tags: iphone

I have this class that has a delegate method. Its delegate has a navigationController.

I am trying to send a message to this navigationController from inside that class. Something like:

```
[delegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

I am receiving the message: **error: accessing unknown 'navigationController' getter method**

when I am inside the delegate, I can access its navigationController using

```
self.navigationController
```

How do I set the getter on that class, so this will work?

thanks.

Comment: is the navigationController a property of the delegate? you can only access properties with dot notation.

Comment: I have this: Main App Delegate > RootViewController > MyClass... navigationController is a property of the main app delegate, but I can access it from RootViewController using self.navigationController. Now I am on MyClass. RootViewController is the delegate of MyClass. How do I access, from MyClass the navigationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigationController` is a property of a typical UIViewController. If you cast the `delegate` to UIViewController*, the error will go away:

```
[((UIViewController *)delegate).navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Note that you'd better make sure that `delegate` is indeed a UIViewController instance. Otherwise, your app will crash.

EDIT: Off the top of my head, there are three ways to cast C pointers, using the above example:

```
((UIViewController *) delegate).navigationController;
```

Why nested braces? Because `(UIViewController *) delegate.navigationController` is equivalent to `(UIViewController *) (delegate.navigationController)` due to operator precedence.

```
[(UIViewController *) delegate navigationController];
```

Here we just cast delegate to UIViewController and send it a message.

```
UIViewController *myViewController = (UIViewController *) delegate;
[myViewController navigationController]; // or myViewController.navigationController;
```

All of them are functionally equivalent. I'd go out on a limb and say it's a matter of style which one to choose.

Comment: PEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRFFFFFFFFFFFFFEEEEEEEEEEEECCCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT !!!!!!!!!  Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: can you explain me the logic behind this? I cannot understand what ((UIViewController *)delegate) is doing. if the delegate is already a viewController why do I have to tell Xcode it is a viewController? I suppose I was trying to access a property on that delegate, like myProperty. How should I access it?

Comment: Look at how you *declared* `delegate`. For example, if it's declared as `id`, the compiler thinks it *is* `id`, but objects of type `id` don't have any properties, hence the error. You can simply declare `delegate` as `UIViewController *` or (if that's not convenient in your code) you can simply cast `id` to `UIViewController *`, essentially to a pointer to a different structure.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks, but if my delegate has properties, then I should call them as delegate.myProperty ? I have tried that and it won't work.

Comment: If `delegate.myProperty` yields a compiler error, most likely, `delegate` is *declared* to be a type which doesn't have `myProperty`. How do you declare `delegate` (most likely it's an instance variable found in the @interface)?

Comment: yes. Delegate is an instance, declared as @property(nonatomic,assign) id<myClassDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Aha, the declaration says that `delegate` is of type `id` (the basic Obj-C class), conforming to `myClassDelegate` protocol. The declaration is certainly too generic, which is common in Cocoa code, so in places where the compiler needs more information you can cast it to the correct pointer type (because you as the author often know much better) like this: `(UIViewController *) delegate`. The extra braces around the whole construct like in the answer above are required to change precedence: type cast first, property second. I hope I'm not too vague.

Comment: type cast first, property second??? I would thought of using just (UIViewController *) delegate, that in my mind is make this delegate referred a view controller. I don't get the second parenthesis. So, according to you it is impossible to access the delegate property (myProperty) using this notation as the class delegate variable is declared as "assign" of type id. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Please see the expanded answer. Formatting in comments is too limited for such things.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..... now it is perfectly clear! thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the delegate in the class that is calling this method. If it is `id` then that's why it doesn't know about the navigationController method. You can cast the delegate to the class it really is if it's the same every time, and import that classes header file so it knows that there is a member navigationController. It's also possible you didn't set the navigationController as a property in the delegate file.